# Visual Studio Repeater: Using more than one DataRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

My code works if I just have one tableRow, as such:

```
 DataRow tableRow = table.NewRow();
 tableRow["DisplayName"] = sqlReader["DisplayName"].ToString();
 table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
```

If I add a second one, my Repeater displays nothing and doesn't work:

```
 DataRow tableRow = table.NewRow();
 tableRow["DisplayName"] = sqlReader["DisplayName"].ToString();
 tableRow["ColumnName"] = sqlReader["ColumnName"].ToString();
 table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
```

What is the proper code to add multiple of these?

**EDIT:**

I also tried this but didn't work:

```
 DataRow tableRow = table.NewRow();
 tableRow["DisplayName"] = sqlReader["DisplayName"].ToString();
 table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
 DataRow tableRow2 = table.NewRow();
 tableRow2["ColumnName"] = sqlReader["ColumnName"].ToString();
 table.Rows.Add(tableRow2);
```

And here is my Stored procedure code:

```
SELECT DisplayName AS DisplayName
    FROM FormField
    WHERE EventId = @EventId AND 
    FormId = @FormId AND 
    Visible = 1
    UNION
    SELECT ColumnName AS ColumnName
    FROM FormField
    WHERE EventId = @EventId AND 
    FormId = @FormId AND 
    Visible = 1
```

**EDIT: C#**

```
  DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("DisplayName", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("ColumnName", typeof(string));

using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    sqlConn2.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
                        sqlCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        sqlCmd2.CommandText = "spGetFormFields";
                        sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = eventId;
                        sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = formId;
                        sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd2.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (sqlReader.Read())
                            {
                                DataRow tableRow = table.NewRow();
                                tableRow["DisplayName"] = sqlReader["DisplayName"].ToString();
                                table.Rows.Add(tableRow);
                                DataRow tableRow2 = table.NewRow();
                                tableRow2["ColumnName"] = sqlReader["ColumnName"].ToString();
                                table.Rows.Add(tableRow2);
                            }
                            RepeaterForm.DataSource = table;
                            RepeaterForm.DataBind();
                        }

                        sqlConn2.Close();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks, I updated my question.

Comment: What code do you use to bind the data to the repeater?

Comment: @Crowcoder Added code

Comment: @RockOn  I suggest you use a `SqlDataAdapter` to `Fill` the `DataTable` instead of looping over a reader. Also, your `ExecuteNonQuery()` is serving no purpose.

Comment: Okay thank you. Could you provide an example of how I could implement that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this. The `SqlDataAdapter` can fill a datatable automatically. It can also make inserts, updates and deletes if you need to but not as shown:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString)) 
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand())
{
    sqlConn2.Open();
    sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlConn2;
    sqlCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCmd2.CommandText = "spGetFormFields";
    sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = eventId;
    sqlCmd2.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = formId;

    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd2))
    {
        da.Fill(Table);
        RepeaterForm.DataSource = table;
        RepeaterForm.DataBind();
    }

    sqlConn2.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Crowcoders comment above regarding the column names being all messed up.

If you do want to do it just that way, I suggest you may want to try change your query  to

`SELECT DisplayName AS DisplayName, ColumnName AS ColumnName
    FROM FormField
    WHERE EventId = @EventId AND 
    FormId = @FormId AND 
    Visible = 1`

See if that gives you the desired results. Though, I would still do it the way @Crowcoder is suggesting.

Comment: I tried putting this answer - because its not really an answer - as a comment - but it kept giving me some error due to the @ - so i gave up and posted it as an answer.

Comment: Yes that gives me what I want, thank you! Yeah if there is a better way to do it, I would like to implement that instead.